# Razor page <A> Label takes ViewContext.Routing.Value id instead of given ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

As my title already explains
I am building a small Twitter Clone for a school project and while i want to go to someones profile page if i click on the poster name.

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Profile">@userController.GetUser(post.UserId).DisplayName</a><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Profile">@userController.GetUser(post.UserId).DisplayName</a>
```

This only gets me so far that i can get the logged in username id via url and looking at it's own profile. well nice but i need to be able to get to other profiles aswell

I've also tried this

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Profile" asp-route-userId="@post.UserId">@userController.GetUser(post.UserId).DisplayName</a>
```

But everytime i do that my url routing is off it will be like this:

```
Profile/3c126298-32f8-471e-8597-69c71c333df8?userId=f5c01788-97d9-4426-881a-53469e8c44f8
```

And it immediatly errors ofcourse.

Does anybody know how I can resolve this issue because i've tried searching for it on the Interwebz but i dont know how to fomulate the question so im not getting any results

Controller code:

```
        [Route("Profile/{id}")]
        public IActionResult Profile(string userId)
        {
            return View(userId);
        }
```

Razor Page

```
@using SpackkApiMVC.Controllers
@model SpackkApiMVC.Models.PostModel

<style>
    .scrollable {
      background-color: rgba(255, 230, 204, 0.2);
    }
    .container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 70%;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">

        <!-- User profile -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">

          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="profile__avatar">
              <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar5.png" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="profile__header">
              <h4>@user.DisplayName <small>Administrator</small></h4>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- User info -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">User info</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table profile__table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
                  <td>United States</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th><strong>Company name</strong></th>
                  <td>Simpleqode.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th><strong>Position</strong></th>
                  <td>Front-end developer</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Community -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Community</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table profile__table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th><strong>Comments</strong></th>
                  <td>58584</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th><strong>Member since</strong></th>
                  <td>Jan 01, 2016</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th><strong>Last login</strong></th>
                  <td>1 day ago</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Latest posts -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Latest posts</h4>
          </div>
          @foreach (PostModel post in postController.GetPosts(user.Id))
          {
            <div class="scrollable">
              <h5 class="card-title"><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Profile" >@userController.GetUser(post.UserId).DisplayName</a></h5>
              <div class="card-body">

                <p class="card-text" name="post.id">
                  @post.Body <br/><br/>

                  <img src="../images/upvote.png" height="15" width="15"/> &nbsp;@postController.GetLikeCount(post.Id)
                  @if (postController.IsLiked(user.Id, post.Id))
                  {
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="UnLike" asp-route-userId="@user.Id" asp-route-postId="@post.Id"class="btn-link" >UnLike</a>
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Like" asp-route-userId="@user.Id" asp-route-postId="@post.Id" class="btn-link" >Like</a>
                  }
                  <br/>
                  <small class="text-muted">@post.Date.ToShortDateString() - @post.Date.ToShortTimeString()</small>
                  <hr>
                </p>

              </div>
            </div>
          }
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">


      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your route param name and action param names are not consistent. You have `{id}` in your route, but then `userId` in your action signature. They should be named the same. The route would be correct, technically if you specified `asp-route-id`, instead of `asp-route-userId`:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Profile" asp-route-id="@post.UserId">@userController.GetUser(post.UserId).DisplayName</a>
```

That would then give you a URL like:

```
Profile/f5c01788-97d9-4426-881a-53469e8c44f8
```

However, since the param name doesn't line up, `userId` would be null.

Comment: Alright I tried this. It does this now sadly it can't find the razor page of /profile/ anymore since it will look for the page named after the GUID i send through

I am out of my mind atm and have no clue how to fix that either